# Were ῾ (δασεία) and ᾿ (ψιλή) formed from ├, ┤ (H) respectively?

Tags: ancient-greek, alphabet

> Στο λατινικό αλφάβητο, όπως και στην αττική διάλεκτο, αποδόθηκε γραπτά με το γράμμα Η, από το οποίο άλλωστε προέρχεται και η δασεία. Συγκεκριμένα, το σύμβολο της δασείας αποτελεί απλοποίηση του ├ (το αριστερό μισό του Ήτα).

Translation (rough):

> In the Latin alphabet, as well as in Attic Greek, it (daseia) is replaced with the letter H; besides, that's where the symbol came from. Specifically, it's a simplified version of ├ (left half of Eta).

Source: [Wikipedia: Δασεία](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%94%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%B1)

---

> Η ψιλή προέρχεται από απλοποίηση του ┤, του δεξιού κομματιού του Η [...]

Translation (rough):

> Psili is a simplified version of ┤, the right half of H (Eta) [...]

Source: [Wikipedia: Ψιλή](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A8%CE%B9%CE%BB%CE%AE)

---

├ and ┤ form an H - ├┤. This is how daseia is pronounced in words Latin, etc. borrowed (e.g. Homer).

Is this true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you follow the Wiki links back enough (to [this page](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%89%CF%84%CE%B1)), you do get a citation for this: Jeffery's *The Local Scripts of Archaic Greece* (Wiki says p. 28, but it actually occurs on p. 29). This is an older monograph, but it's still standard, and I even remember using it in my palaeography class in college.

In tracing the different forms of eta, Jeffery's mentions one type, the Ͱ form of eta found in Italy, and the "subsequent palaeographical history [of which], the *spiritus asper*, is well known; its place of origin may have been Taras (p. 183), for most of the early examples are from that area."

It should be noted that at this time, the letter H in some Greek dialects was used not as a long E, but as the aspiration itself. (Some alphabets even had H both as a vowel and as aspiration.) See e.g. Smyth §14:

> The sign for rough breathing is derived from H, which in the Old Attic alphabet (2 a) was used to denote *h*. Thus, HO *ὁ the*. After H was used to denote *η*, one half (Ͱ) was used for *h* (about 300 B.C.), and, later, the other half (┤) for the smooth breathing. From Ͱ and ┤ comes the forms ῾ and ᾿.

<sub>Note: ┤ isn't the proper unicode character, and I'm not sure what is.</sub>